Metadata Relationship to the same custom metadata type
I want to link the same custom metadata type to itself using Metadata Relationship.
Example:
Metadata api name: My_Custom_Metadata__mdt
Metadata Relationship: Parent__c
I want to connect My_Custom_Metadata__mdt to another My_Custom_Metadata__mdt using Parent__c.
It seems like I don't have that in the dropdown for Metadata Relationship inside salesforce. Does anybody know why? Is there a solution around this?

The documentation states

From the detail page of your custom metadata type, click New under Custom Fields.
For the field type, select Metadata Relationship.
Select either:
Another custom metadata type that you want to be the child of the active custom metadata type.
Entity Definition (Represents the metadata of a standard or custom object)

Normally, one would expect to see this self-referential restriction in the Custom Metadata Relationship Considerations help page but it isn't there. Consider filing a doc feedback.
As for a workaround, consider these examples from the Bill-of-Materials use case
